# How to send XML request to eBay?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I send XML request to ebay, but it didn't respond anything. I checked each field like runame, header, and curl, but still not seem any error.Can anyone solve this problem?

```
$runame = "Th_c_L__B_-ThcLB-SynEbay-S-swfednxx";
$xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
        '<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'.
                 '<RuName>'.$runame.'</RuName>'.
        '</GetSessionIDRequest>';

$headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
            'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL' => '889',
            'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME' => $devId,
            'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' => $appId,
            'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME' => $certId,
            'X-EBAY-API-SITEID' => '0',
            'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME' => 'GetSessionID'
    );

    $url = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);


    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What happens when you send the same XML with command line curl?

Comment: There must be some way to get more information on the curl result? (HTTP Code, headers, etc.) I suggest digging and evaluating what you find there.

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself that it's need to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false, because Ebay requite https and I run it in localhost, which have no SSL certification. In addition, the $headers array MUST NOT use association.

```
$runame = "Th_c_L__B_-ThcLB-SynEbay-S-swfednxx";
$xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
        '<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'.
             '<RuName>'.$runame.'</RuName>'.
        '</GetSessionIDRequest>';

$headers = array(
            'Content-Type: text/xml',
            'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 911',
            'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $this->devId,
            'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $this->appId,
            'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: '. $this->certId,
            'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0',
            'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetSessionID'
);

$url = 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```